# Good way to add some space between html table rows using css? Works across all browsers including IE6

Tags: html, css

What's a good way to add some space between html table rows using css? Should work in all browsers including IE6. Should use id or class so it doesn't affect every table in the site. Prefer to declare the css at the table level. Don't want to use empty tr's to simulate a blank row. css should not affect any inner tables.

Logically I tried this but margins don't work with tr's:

```
.someclass tr
{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
.someclass td {padding-bottom: 20px;}
```

It's unfortunately not that intuitive but it works on IE6 and all the other browsers.  You can also do it with a border:

```
.someclass td {border-bottom: 20px solid white;}
```

**Edit**

To exclude an inner table you could use:

```
.someclass td td {padding-bottom: 0px;}
```

Comment: Both have the undesirable effect of adding space inside the column. So if I have a checkbox inside the column, there's extra space below the checkboxes and the checkbox looks off. Inner tables inherit the paddings too. How to exclude them?

Comment: Do you have nested tables?  Could you provide a sample on jsfiddle for us to look at?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you are referring to with the checkbox.   I edited my answer to show how you could exclude inner tables from inheriting the padding.

Answer (score 2):

[*border-spacing*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#separated-borders) is the right way to go, but [doesn't fulfill all your requirements](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html).

Still, you could use it in combination with a little browser-detection: if IE < 8, use a little javascript to add some cellspacing.

Comment: Doesn't work in all IE's. I would go for blank rows instead of using js +browser detection.

Comment: @Tony, If you had read the link provided, the solution is simple. IE<8 does not support `border-spacing` and `border-spacing` overrides `cellpadding` element attribute. Set `cellpadding` attribute on the table, then also define the `border-spacing` in the css.

Comment: @Kevin cellspacing adds extra space around the td from the four sides which i don't want. I only want more space between the rows keeping everything else untouched. Just like two div's, one above the other, with a gap between them. No extra space to the top, left & right sides. Logically like the css I have in my post.

Comment: @Tony, the progressive enhancement way to handle this would be to not have the spacing for IE<8 OR to accept the fact that IE<8 will have space on the sides. If you want something that will work in all browsers, add an empty tr...

Answer (score 0):

Add following rule to tr and it should work

```
float: left
```

Sample (Open it in IE9 offcourse :) ):
http://jsfiddle.net/zshmN/

Comment: float:left doesn't make sense for a table row.. If you comment it out it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr><td><br></td></tr>
```

The above creates a gap between 2 rows with the `<br>` tag

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the border to be too big/thick (with `border-spacing`), you could use `padding` on the `td`.

http://jsfiddle.net/zzJ9Z/

Comment: `border-spacing` does not increase the `border-width`. It adds space between the borders of `td` elements (but you need to use the default `border-collapse` of `separate`). Thus, the `background` that would be visible is the `background` set in the `tr` or other parent element.

Comment: How do you stop innertables from inheriting properties from parent table? See innertable at http://jsfiddle.net/zzJ9Z/3/